# OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor for CXF

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions, cxf

I have a Web service application based on **JPA** (Hibernate), **Spring** and **CXF**.
I am facing some lazy-load exceptions after transactional business methods (because I need some extra beans to be rendered in the rpesentation layer), and I wanted to give a try to the OpenSession/**EntityManagerInView** pattern.

Please do not argue this choice, we are just giving it a try.

The issue is that, since I am using **CXFServlet**, instead of standard Spring Servlet, I cannot use **OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter** in web.xml.

I cannot use either **OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor** which applies as a WebRequest Interceptor (and does not work with CXF interceptor/filters).

Finally I am aware of the [HibernateInterceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateInterceptor.html), an AOP proxy which wraps any method  into a session. But still : this one is for the Hibernate API, not JPA API (I am using **EntityManagerFactory**, rather than **SessionFactory**).

So, are you aware of either :

- A **HibernateInterceptor** for the JPA API (**EntityManagerInterceptor** ?)
- A way to adapt a Spring **WebRequestInterceptor** into a **[JAX-RSfilter](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-filters.html)** ?
- Any other solution ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Once again, I finally found what I wanted ...
There is actually a [JpaInterceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaInterceptor.html) that does what I want (it seems deprecated though. I do not really understand why).

Here is the resulting configuration that works like a charm, with a bit of auto proxy by name :

```
   <bean id="jpaInterceptor" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaInterceptor"> 
     <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" /> 
   </bean> 

   <bean id="jpaAutoProxy" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanNameAutoProxyCreator" >
    <property name="beanNames">
      <list>
        <value>myService1</value>
        <value>myService2</value>
        <value>...</value>
      </list>
    </property>
    <property name="interceptorNames">
       <list><value>jpaInterceptor</value></list>
    </property>
  </bean>

<jaxrs:server id="services" address="/">

    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="myService1" />
        <ref bean="myService2" />
        <ref bean="..." />

    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>
```